# Input filter/val output escape zf2 correctly?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, xss

Do I correctly understand, that I need to escape in view smth like this:

```
 <div id="search-box">
        <?php $escaper = new Zend\Escaper\Escaper('utf-8'); ?>
        <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $escaper->escapeHtml($this->languageText('TEXT_SEARCH_OUR_SITE',"Search Our Site"));
       ?>" name="query" id="query" />
        <div class="search-box-bk"></div>
    </div>
```

And how correctly filter, or validate in controller this line:

```
$this->view->phrase = $this->getRequest()->getParam('phrase','');
```

Answer (score 1):

How to escape something correctly depends on the context. In your example the variable is being output in a HTML attribute, so you should use `escapeHtmlAttr`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($this->languageText('TEXT_SEARCH_OUR_SITE',"Search Our Site"));
   ?>" name="query" id="query" />
```

There is a [list of escape functions in the overview of the component](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.escaper.introduction.html#overview).

As for what you need to do in the controller, the answer is: probably nothing, but it depends what you are going to use "phrase" for.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answer. Seems like this doesn't work in my issue. I tried this before.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What output are you getting?